# can't start intent startActivityForResult from class

Tags: java, android

I will be very happy if someone can help me, because I'm new at object programming. My problem is: I'm writting some app with bluetooth communication. I wrote all methods and successfully connect and transfer data between devices in *MainActivity.class*. I have also one *SearchActivity.class* which shows all devices in range on List, so user can pick one. Device is then passed through Intent to *MainActivity*, where connection starts. But because of nature of my app I must created separate class, just for Bluetooth communication called *BluetoothService.class*. I moved all methods for Bluetooth and other stuff to *BluetoothService.class.*
 Now I even can't compile my project, because I get error at creating Intent for SearchActivity, I also get error startActivityForResult and onActivityResult methods.

First error is: *The constructor Intent(BluetoothService, Class) is undefined*

Second error: *The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type BluetoothService*

```
public void startConnection() {
    // Create an intent for SearchActivity 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
    //start SearchActivity through intent and expect for result. 
    //The result is based on result code, which is REQUEST_DISCOVERY
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCOVERY);              
}
```

When I was calling method *startConnection()* from MainActivity everything worked, but now I it doesn't. I think the problem is, that I can't create new Activity from non-activity class.

Next error is in onActivityResult method: *RESULT_OK cannot be resolved to a variable*

```
//on ActivityResult method is called, when other activity returns result through intent!
//when user selected device in SearchActivity, result is passed through intent with //requestCode, resultCode (intent data + requestCode + resultCode)
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode != REQUEST_DISCOVERY) {
    Log.d("Debug", ">>intent REQUEST_DISCOVERY failed!");
    return;
    }
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
    Log.d("Debug", ">>intent RESULT_OK failed!");
    return;
    }
    Log.d("Debug", ">>onActivityResult!");
    final BluetoothDevice device = data.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

    Log.d(device.getName(), "Name of Selected Bluetoothdevice");


    new Thread () {
        public void run() {
        //call connect function with device argument
        connect(device);
        };
    }.start();
    }
```

Please, tell me how can I solve this. If you need more info or code tell me. Thanks.

```
public class SearchActivity  extends ListActivity
{
    //name of LxDevices, that will be shown on search
    private String nameOfLxDevice = "DEBUG";

    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    /* Get Default Adapter */
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    /* Storage the BT devices */
    private List<BluetoothDevice> devices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    /* Discovery is Finished */
    private volatile boolean discoveryFinished;


    /* Start search device */ 
    private Runnable discoveryWorker = new Runnable() {
        public void run() 
        {
            //To start discovering devices, simply call startDiscovery(). The process is asynchronous and the method will 
            //immediately return with a boolean indicating whether discovery has successfully started.
            mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            Log.d("debug", ">>Starting Discovery");
            for (;;) 
            {
                if (discoveryFinished) 
                {
                    Log.d("debug", ">>Finished");
                    break;
                }
                try 
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e){}
            }
        }
    }; 

    /* when discovery is finished, this will be called */
    //Your application must register a BroadcastReceiver for the ACTION_FOUND Intent in order to receive information about each device discovered.
    //For each device, the system will broadcast the ACTION_FOUND Intent. This Intent carries the extra fields EXTRA_DEVICE and EXTRA_CLASS,
    //containing a BluetoothDevice and a BluetoothClass, respectively

    private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            /* get the search results */
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);               
                //add it on List<BluetoothDevice>
                devices.add(device);
                //show found LxDevice on list
                showDevices();
            }           
        }
    };

    private BroadcastReceiver discoveryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  
        {
            /* unRegister Receiver */
            Log.d("debug", ">>unregisterReceiver");
            unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
            unregisterReceiver(this);
            discoveryFinished = true;
        }
    };

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

        /* BT isEnable */
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
        {
            Log.w("debug", ">>BT is disable!");
            finish();
            return;
        }
        /* Register Receiver*/
        IntentFilter discoveryFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(discoveryReceiver, discoveryFilter);
        IntentFilter foundFilter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, foundFilter);


        /* show a dialog "Scanning..." */ 
        SamplesUtils.indeterminate(SearchActivity.this, handler, "Scanning for LX devices..", discoveryWorker, new OnDismissListener() {
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog)
            {
                for (; mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering();) {
                    // Discovery is resource intensive.  Make sure it isn't going on when you attempt to connect and pass your message.
                    mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                }
                discoveryFinished = true;
            }
        }, true); 
    }

    /* Show devices list */
    private void showDevices()
    {
        //Create a list of strings
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0, size = devices.size(); i < size; ++i) {
            StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
            BluetoothDevice d = devices.get(i);
            b.append(d.getName());
            b.append('\n');
            b.append(d.getAddress());
            String s = b.toString();
            list.add(s);
        }

        Log.d("debug", ">>showDevices");
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }

    /* Select device */
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("debug", ">>Click device");
        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, devices.get(position));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
        finish();
    }

}
```

In MainActivity I am doing:

```
// Initialize the BluetoothChatService to perform bluetooth connections
    mBluetoothService = new BluetoothService(this);
```

Constructor in BluetoothService is:

```
 public BluetoothService(Context context) {

    }
```

connect method:

```
protected void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
    //Create a Socket connection: need the server's UUID number of registered
    BluetoothSocket socket = null;
    socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);         
    socket.connect();
        //Create temporary input and output stream
         InputStreamtmpIn=socket.getInputStream();                                                      
    OutputStream tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();

    //for use purposes
    mmSocket = socket;
    mmOutStream = tmpOut;
    mmInStream = tmpIn;

    tmpOut.write("Device connected..".getBytes());

    //start Thread for receiving data over bluetooth
    //dataReceiveThread.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Colibri2BB BT", "", e);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Do you call startDiscovery in SearchActivity?

Comment: Does your BluettoothService class extend Service? And also have to show which class your RESULT_OK belongs to, like SomeClass.RESULT_OK if RESULT_OK is static of course.

Comment: Yes, I call startDiscovery in SearchActivity.

Comment: No, my BluetoothService.class doesn't extend Service...

Comment: Now I edit to: public class BluetoothService extends Service, and add BluetoothService.RESULTK_OK and this two errrs are gone. Now I still got only second error.

Comment: Can you post your SearchActivity

Comment: okay, you have the context in your class but you let it go without doing any thing. you should create a Context instance to hold it globally to your class like shown in answers below. Also for RESULT_OK you can use Activity.RESULT_OK

Comment: I do not know what is your app doing so I do not if service is appropriate. For now you should not make your app extends service. I will post the answer.

Comment: Can you post your connect method. I want to know if you can make it a static method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `BluettoothService` class is not a context and to initialise an Intent you need a context.So try creating your class like this:

```
    public class BluettoothService{

    Activity activity;

    BluettoothService(Activity activity){
    this.activity=activity;
    }
    public void startConnection() {
    // Create an intent for SearchActivity 
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SearchActivity.class);
    //start SearchActivity through intent and expect for result. 
    //The result is based on result code, which is REQUEST_DISCOVERY
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCOVERY);              
    } 


}
```

And you can create the `BluettoothService` class this way from any activity:

```
BluettoothService bluetooth=new BluettoothService(this);
```

Edit:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode != REQUEST_DISCOVERY) {
Log.d("Debug", ">>intent REQUEST_DISCOVERY failed!");
return;
}
if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
Log.d("Debug", ">>intent RESULT_OK failed!");
return;
}
Log.d("Debug", ">>onActivityResult!");
final BluetoothDevice device = data.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

Log.d(device.getName(), "Name of Selected Bluetoothdevice");


new Thread () {
    public void run() {
    //call connect function with device argument
    connect(device);
    };
}.start();
}
```

Comment: I created class BluetothService like you said, add to constructor this.context=context; I still got error on startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCOVERY);

Comment: ERORR is:The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type BluetoothService

Comment: sorry, my bad! try context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCOVERY); if fails please let me know

Comment: It failed again...error:The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type Context

Comment: Thank you very much, it works...now I only got problem, that when program exit SearchActivity on finish() method, it doesn't continuous onActivityResult method, as I see in debuger...I have to figure it out why...maybe you know what coud be the reason? tnx again!

Comment: I don't you should call finish(). I think you should let it return something like null or Activity.RESULT_CANCELED.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use  `this` of a Service to start an `ActivityForResult`

Answer (score 0):

You should to specify the `@override` for the `onActivityResult()`.

Your code should to be put into a class who extends 'activity' (android.app.Activity).
It's for that you have also this :

```
Next error is in onActivityResult method: *RESULT_OK cannot be resolved to a variable*
```

This cannot be resolved because **your class don't extends 'Activity'**

Answer (score 0):

//create this class that hold application context.

```
public class Application_Manager extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Application_Manager.context = getApplicationContext();

    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return Application_Manager.context;
    }
}
```

//use this class getAppcontext() to get context in non-activity class.

```
public class BluettoothService{

    static Context context=Application_Manager.getAppContext();
    public void startConnection() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SearchActivity.class);
    context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCOVERY);//change edited              
    } 


}
```

Comment: I also tried this, but I still get error at startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCVERY); ERROR: The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type BluetoothService...Please, help!

Comment: public class BluettoothService{

    static Context context=Application_Manager.getAppContext();
    public void startConnection() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SearchActivity.class);
    context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCOVERY);              
    } 


}

Comment: see the change i have done in startactivity call-context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCOVERY); hope this will solve your issue

Comment: I called context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_DISCOVERY); and still got error:The method startActivityForResult(Intent, int) is undefined for the type Context

Comment: check context value whether it is null.from where u use bluetoothservice class is in from activity.if yes then pass context of that activity to constructor of bluetooth class constructor and use that context for starting activity thr bluetooth service.

Comment: I check context value in MainActivity, where I will use BluetoothService. I checked with if(mBluetoothService.context == null)
Log.d("context", "null");
else Log.d("context", "!null"); and it is not null...

Comment: Yes, I want start connection from MainActivity and use some Bluetooth methdods from BluetoothService class, writeByte() from example. At first I had everything for Bluetooth in MainActivity, but now I want it separated in BluetoothService class. I also want to use methods of BluetoothService in some other class Decoding, that's why I wanted my own BT class, that I can use it from everywhere that I will need it. Is that not possible??

Comment: yes u can u need to maintain context object of main activity that u can pass thr construtor of each class